# Trouble unstaging, deleting even untracking a file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have newly cloned a private repository noticing that it has already a staged file that is on status `deleted`:

issuing `git status` gives me this:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    rootfolder/site/templates/article.php
```

I wanted to make this working directory clean, the trouble comes when I unstage, untrack or even delete gives me error something like below:

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false reset -q HEAD
>   -- "rootfolder/site/templates/article.php "
>
> error: Invalid path 'rootfolder/site/templates/article.php ' fatal:
>   make_cache_entry failed for path
>   'rootfolder/site/templates/article.php '

Any advise on how can i resolve this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `git checkout rootfolder/site/templates/article.php`

Comment: How can a new clone have anything staged? Stage is a local thing, while cloning works with a remote repository.

Comment: @YamMarcovic already did that gives me errors too `error: pathspec 'rootfolder/site/templates/article.php' did not match any file(
s) known to git.`

Comment: @choroba, yeah that suprised me too!, first time I've encountered it, but really it did have a staged deleted file when i first clone it.

Comment: Are you sure the directory hadn't existed before you cloned the repo?

Comment: @choroba, its a new directory(actually second attempt), thinking that it would solve the problem if i created a new one

Comment: If you use Windows or other OS with case insensitive paths then it's possible that in repo there are two files: rootfolder/site/templates/article.php and rootfolder/site/templates/Article.php . On checkout one overwrote the other and that's the reason why you see it as deleted. I don't think there's other solution than to use OS with case sensitive paths.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a Windows/Linux thing. My travis build (on Linux vm) ran some tests in my code, creating files in `C:/SomeFolder/someTestResult.file`. It then proceeded to commit these changes and push to github in the `C:/` folder.

The trouble came when I tried to `git clone` on my windows machine:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:awesome/somegitrepo.git
Cloning into 'somegitrepo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 14, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 940 (delta 5), reused 13 (delta 5), pack-reused 926
Receiving objects: 100% (940/940), 500.23 KiB | 364.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (373/373), done.
error: Invalid path 'C:/SomeFolder/someTestResult.file'
```

Clearly something went wrong because of the `C:/` folder. GIT on windows saw the `C:/` not as a local directory, but as the root directory, so the Linux local `someTestResult.file` was not there on the Windows git repo. I guess it then assumed it was deleted and staged the deletion even before I made any changes whatsoever.

---

My solution was to open up a Linux terminal ([WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)) and delete the file from repo and push in order to clean the remote repository.

So basically (in the WSL):

```
$ git clone git@github.com:awesome/somegitrepo.git
$ rm -rf C:/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Removed residue test files'
$ git push
```

I also changed my tests to not produce strange directories and put the generated test files in the `.gitignore` anyway.